# htacess rewrite rule gives 500 internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I don't know much about htaccess rewrite rule. I have tried something like this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /ebook/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^book/id/([^/]+)$ book.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**First rule for hide file extension.**

**second rule for redirecting to another page with id**

in html,

`<a href="/ebook/book/id/8">click here</a>`

**book.php is empty file**

but it gives 500 internal server.

Comment: Do you have root access to the server? If so, make sure mod_rewrite is loaded

Comment: i  removed first rule, kept second rule as it is. it works fine.

Comment: Ok. lemme just figure out what it wrong

Comment: Check your error log just once, and paste the latest output after you access the page